# how to get the client IP in spyne service

Tags: python, spyne

I use the Spyne lib as soap web service and implement a interface to provide registration function for clients.

But I don't know how to get the client IP in function body.

```
    @srpc(String,String,String,_returns=String)
def register():
        #I need record client IP address
        return "hello"
```

Comment: It's not possible to answer this as without knowing which transport you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Change `@srpc` to `@rpc` like this:

```
@rpc(String,String,String,_returns=String)

def register(ctx, str1, str2, str3):

    #I need record client IP address
    print ctx.transport.req["REMOTE_ADDR"]
    return "hello"
```

As I understand, when you use `@rpc` it gives the function as the first parameter an object with all the information of configuration, headers and some methods.